# Headless does not work after closing app

Tags: react-native

I have used Headless from React Native. 
I have setup all configuration for it and run my test script as showed in offical site tutorial.

It works when my app is working in foreground. 
Whenever I close or switch another app, my background script also stop working.

Is there any option to allow code to work in background after closing app?

Comment: how did you fix this issue ?

Comment: @MukundKumar I used third party library which is written in Native language. I could not find other solution